# ERROR: syntax error at or near "END" SQL state: 42601

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

i have a question, i have this problem when I try to execute the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION USP_IP_CREA_AUDITORIA_VER_CONSTRASENA
(p_usuarioObservado td_codigo10
,p_codigoEmpresaObservado td_codigo10
,p_usuario td_codigo10
,p_codigoEmpresa td_codigo10
,p_direccionIP td_ip_auditoria) RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO IP_MV_AUDITORIA_VER_CONSTRASENA(cod_usuario_observado, cod_empresa_observado, cod_usuario_registro, cod_empresa, des_ip_registro)
                                    VALUES(p_usuarioObservado, p_codigoEmpresaObservado, p_usuario, p_codigoEmpresa, p_direccionIP)

END;


$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "END"
LINE 13: END;
         ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "END"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 496
```

Comment: add a semicolon after `p_direccionIP)` -->> `p_direccionIP);`

Comment: Thanks so much for the help!!!

Comment: If you found the answer helpful please accept it as answer, so that it can help others.

Answer (score 6):

Use semi colon at the last of your insert query. Hope this helps you.